# How to free a part of contiguous allocated memory in c?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, free

I am new to C. I have a program that allocates some memory using `calloc()` that store pointers. Those pointers point to places in memory where I store data of people. one pointer for each person. So when I need to delete the data, I `free()` the pointer to these data. But the memory with the pointers still has that one. I want to free that place too. As I know, I can't say `free(ptr+5)` for example. How can I do that?

Comment: free(ptr[5]); ptr[5] = NULL;

Comment: Can you give a small example of your code, please? I am not sure what is your organisation in memory.

Comment: Describing code in just words is often unclear and prone to misinterpretation. Please provide actual code as a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the situation you are asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't free the start or middle of an allocated block and leave the end of the allocated block alone; so (for deleting an entry in an array):

- move everything after the entry you're removing up to the end of the allocated block towards the start of the allocated block; so that the piece to be removed is at the end
- use `realloc()` to reduce the size of the allocated block (to free the piece at the end).

Dodgy example (assuming that `i` is the entry you want to free):

```
    memmove(&myArray[i], &myArray[i+1], (total_entries - 1 - i) * sizeof(myArray[0]) );
    temp = realloc(myArray, total_entries - 1 * sizeof(myArray[0]));
    if(temp == NULL) {
        /* Ooops. Need to handle the error somehow */
    } else {
        myArray = temp;
        total_entries--;
    }
```

Comment: Yep, that's basically it.